# change the size of Cursor returned from LoadCursorFromFile

Tags: c#, winforms, cursor

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern IntPtr LoadCursorFromFile(string path);

public static Cursor LoadCustomCursor(string path)
        {
            try {

                IntPtr hCurs = LoadCursorFromFile(path);
                if (hCurs == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Win32Exception();
                var curs = new Cursor(hCurs);

                // Note: force the cursor to own the handle so it gets released properly
                var fi = typeof(Cursor).GetField("ownHandle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
                fi.SetValue(curs, true);
                return curs;


            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(ex, true);
                return Cursor.Current;
            }
        }
```

am loading the `cursor` image from file , no matter what is the image size the `cursor` size will be 32*32 , how would I force it to load the image actual size?

Answer (score 0):

This may only be a partial answer for your exact requirements. You could use the Tag property of the Cursor to store a Size object. In my example below I am creating a cursor from a bitmap which may be larger than the default 32X32 so I know what the size is when the cursor is created.

```
    public static Cursor CreateCursor(Bitmap bm, int xHotspot, int yHotspot, bool resize = true)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = (resize) ? ((Bitmap)ResizeBitmap(bm, 32, 32)).GetHicon() : bm.GetHicon();
        IconInfo inf = new IconInfo();
        GetIconInfo(ptr, ref inf);
        inf.xHotspot = xHotspot;
        inf.yHotspot = yHotspot;
        inf.fIcon = false;
        IntPtr cursorPtr = CreateIconIndirect(ref inf);
        if (inf.hbmColor != IntPtr.Zero) { DeleteObject(inf.hbmColor); }
        if (inf.hbmMask != IntPtr.Zero) { DeleteObject(inf.hbmMask); }
        if (ptr != IntPtr.Zero) { DestroyIcon(ptr); }
        Cursor c = new Cursor(cursorPtr);
        c.Tag = (resize) ? new Size(32, 32) : bm.Size;
        return c;
    }
```

I can inspect the Tag property elsewhere in my code using the dynamic keyword - here I am retrieving the Width property from the Size stored in the Tag

```
int cWidth = ((dynamic)cursors[2].Tag).Width
```